# listings (lstinput) not working in tabularx

Tags: errors, listings, tabularx, missing

I know there are plenty of similar questions here, but mine is very simple:

When I build LaTeX files with `latexmk -pdf -xelatex` I often have this error:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<inserted text>
                {
l.8 \end{tabularx}
```

However my LaTeX file is pretty simple, and it builds on My PC, but not on my Docker image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X}
\lstinline{foobar}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y texlive-xetex
RUN apt-get install -y texlive-lang-french
RUN apt-get install -y texlive-fonts-extra
RUN apt-get install -y latexmk

# To make latexmk happy
ENV USER=latex
```

Comment: compiles fine for me. maybe the issue lies somewhere else. what's the log saying?

Comment: @naphaneal Have the log [here](https://gist.github.com/yves-chevallier/4dc21cec35787496a9358a302f2c11d7)

Comment: @naphaneal Have you tried with my Dockerfile?

Comment: @nowox the Docker file installs TeX Live 2015 according to your log, which is a bit old. Maybe you can configure `apt-get` to use a newer repository, or do a 'vanilla' install within Docker (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)?

Comment: @Marijn yes because I install `debian:jessie`

Comment: @nowox maybe it does not make a difference, but given the fact that it works on your PC (which presumably has a newer version of TeX Live) it could be that the error is caused by using old versions, which means that the solution is to use newer versions.

Comment: @nowox no, I don't utilize docker, due to security issues. I tried your code in my TeX environment.